# Lattice ordered group

Tags: group-theory, lattice-orders

It seems the basic fact but I did not get the idea how to prove it. Let $G$ be a partially ordered group. Then $G$ is an $\ell$-group if and only if every pair of positive elements has least upper bound.

Comment: One direction follows from definitions. Have you been able to prove one direction? What have you tried for the other direction?

Comment: Hint: inverses.

Comment: Thank you all. As Cameron said one direction is okay just by definition. I have a problem with the converse part. I was trying to use this idea. Let $c$ and $d$ be any elements of $G$ (let's assume both are neither positive nor negative). Since $G$ is an $\ell$-group, we can write each elements of as the difference of positive elements. Then $c = g_{1}- g_{2}$ and $d = h_{1} - h_{2}$ for some positive elements $ g_{1}, g_{2}, h_{1}, h_{2}$. Then I could not prove $c\wedge d$ exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This follows from the assertion:

A partially ordered group $G$ is an $l$-group if and only if for any $a\in G$ there is the least upper bound of $a$ and $1$.

[Fuchs, L. Partially ordered algebraic systems. Pergamon Press, 1963, chapt.5, sec.1]